# What does "the prototype belongs to the class not the instance" mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I asked the question:

[Why cant I declare a constructor instantiate an object and then access the prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070992/why-cant-i-declare-a-constructor-instantiate-an-object-and-then-access-the-protot)

And you can see that I have marked the answer. I understand the response but Im a bit confused as to what he means by:

```
The prototype belongs to the class, not the instance:
```

Does this mean that javascript has a class in this example? I thought javascript was classless? It only has function constructors... At what point does a function constructor become a class? Is it when you add other members to it using the .prototype accessor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `class` is an OOP term, not really javascript. What is meant is that the prototype belongs to the `constructor`. So in

```
function MyConstructor(prop){
   this.foo = prop || 'foo';
}
MyConstructor.prototype.bar = 'allways bar';
var mc1 = new MyConstructor('I am mc1'), 
    mc2 = new MyConstructor('I am mc2');

alert(mc1.bar) ; //=> allways bar
alert(mc2.bar) ; //=> allways bar
alert(mc1.foo) ; //=> I am mc1
alert(mc2.foo) ; //=> I am mc2
```

`bar` belongs to the constructors (`MyConstructor`) prototype. It will always be 'allways bar', for every instance. `foo` is an instance property (with a default value 'foo') and can be assigned with a different value for every instance.

Comment: Hi, could I ask what 'this.foo = prop || 'foo';' means? Is that an OR symbol?

Comment: Hi Pete2k, yes is an OR symbol. It's shorthand for: if `prop` evaluates to undefined (or null), assign the value 'foo' to `this.prop`. It's often used to make sure some variable gets a (default) value.

Answer (score 1):

Ya prototype of JavaScript is a concept quite similar to class but not exactly the same. Read the article below, it offers one of the best explanations available on internet on this issue.

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

There are no classes in javascript.

Constructors are functions and have a *prototype* property that references an object. You can add functions to that object, or assign a new object to the prototype property to create an inheritance chain:

```
function MyConstructor () {
  // initialise instance
}

MyConstructor.prototype.someMethod = function() {
    // ...
  };

MyConstructor.prototype.anotherMethod = function() {
    // ...
};
```

or replace it with an instance of another constructor:

```
MyConstructor.prototype = new SomeOtherConstructor();

MyConstructor.prototype.constructor = MyConstructor;
```

and so on. Now when an instance of MyConstructor is created:

```
var anInstance = new MyConstructor();
```

The object returned by the constructor has *MyConstructor.prototype* as its internal [[prototype]] property and "inherits" its methods and properties (and those on its entire [[prototype]] chain).

So each instance of *MyConstructor* has its *MyConstructor.prototype* on its prototype chain. Note however that *MyConstructor* doesn't inherit from it's own prototype, it is only used by instances created by *new MyConstructor*.